# change rss feed url structure

Tags: rss

I want to change RSS feed URL structure:

```
<h2><a href="frame.php?u=<?php echo $item->get_permalink();?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $item->get_title();?></a></h2>
```

The above code is RSS URL that redirect to `frame.php` that `iframe` to this website. But the URL looks like this :

```
http://akhbartop.ir/frame.php?u=http://www.irna.ir/fa/News/82283197/
```

I want to change that URL for example like this :

```
http://akhbartop.ir/frame.php?u=News/82283197/
```

Actually, I don't want to show URL website feed to my website.

Comment: Please, add more information why do you use `$item->get_permalink();`. Any add-ons? And please rephrase your question as it's impossible to understand.

Comment: i used simplepie for display feeds from many sites on my website and this is the right permalink format to redirect on that website.but i want to change url.it seems that these feeds are my website posts.i hope you understand what i mean
check url on main topic that is what i mean

Comment: Please edit your question including the missing important information.

Comment: what do you need to know?!!cant understand what i say?!